# ¿Como se puede ordenar palabras en orden alfabético sin usar sort() EN PYTHON?

Tags: python, ordenamiento

Si yo tengo la lista

```
lista=["dora","dira","cesiah","carlos]
```

Yo puedo hacerlo, pero solo teniendo en cuenta la primera letra, pero como sería si tienen la misma letra inicial entonces allí la condición pasaría a la segunda letra y si son iguales se pasaría a la otra letra.

¿Cómo hago para generalizar esa forma así como lo hace sort() pero sin usarlo. Por lo tanto la lista me tendría que salir así

```
"carlos","cesiah","dira","dora"
```

Pero a mi me sale `"cesiah","carlos","dora","dira"`.

ESE ES EL CODIGO QUE HICE:

```
def ordenar_alfabeticamente(lista):
    alfabeto="abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"
    for i in range(1,len(lista)):
        actual=alfabeto.index(lista[i][0])
        palabra_actual=lista[i]
        indice=i
        while indice>0 and alfabeto.index(lista[indice-1][0])>actual:
            lista[indice]=lista[indice-1]
            indice=indice-1
        lista[indice]=palabra_actual
    print(lista)

lista=["julio", "dora", "dira","gillermo","carlos"]
ordenar_alfabeticamente(lista)
```

Comment: Si fueras tan amable, podrías agregar a la pregunta el codigo que tienes hecho hasta ahora (como texto)?

Comment: ¿Y cómo lo haces en base a la primera letra? Porque probablemente el mismo algoritmo te sirva, si en lugar de comparar la primera letra comparas la cadena completa, ya que la comparación entre cadenas se basa en el orden alfabético. Es decir, que `"carlos" < "cesiah"` te va a dar `True`.

Comment: Gracias por editar tu pregunta Jeferson y agregar lo que trataste, no olvides leer [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que preguntas por curiosidad sobre como funcionan las cosas por dentro.

Hay muchos algoritmos de ordenamientos. Los más populares son ordenamiento de burbujas (bubble-sort) y quicksort, cuya descripción puedes encontrar en Internet.

Analizaremos el caso común de como ordenar en orden ascendente.

Aquí mostrare el denominado ordenamiento por inserción. La idea básica es simple: tomas la lista de entrada y vas construyendo una lista de salida ordenada. Para esto recorres la lista de entrada buscando el menor elemento. Cuando lo encuentras, lo agregas a la cola de la lista de salida. Entonces descartas ese valor de la lista de entrada y vuelves a repetir todo. En cada ciclo la lista de entrada pierde un elemento y la lista de salida gana uno.

Cuando la lista de entrada queda vacia, la lista de salida tiene todos los elementos ordenados.

Complicaciones de la vida real: es muy feo destruir o modificar la lista de entrada, así que no lo haremos. Lo que haremos sera acordarnos del valor mínimo detectado en el ciclo anterior, y buscar un nuevo mínimo que sea mayor que ese.

También usaremos un generador: en lugar de armar y retornar de una sola vez la lista ordenada, iremos retornando de a un elemento a la vez, usando `yield` en lugar de `return`.

```
def my_sort(lista):
    """ Generador que ordena una lista de valores homogeneos
    """
    largo = len(lista)
    if largo == 0:
        return  # No hay nada mas que retornar

    idx = 0             # indice del menor elemento.
    min = lista[idx]    # valor del menor elemento.
    min_prev = None     # minimo anterior
    found = True        # Se encontro un minimo.
    
    while found:
        # Buscar el elemento menor que sea mayor al elemento menor en el 
        # ciclo anterior. Ojo: puede que no haya elemento anterior.
        for index in range(largo):
            if lista[index] < min and (min_prev == None or lista[index] > min_prev):
                idx = index
                min = lista[idx]
                found = True


        if found:
            # Entregar el valor encontrado.
            yield min

            # Recorrer el resto de la lista entregando todos los elementos
            # que sean iguales al minimo encontrado.
            for index in range(idx + 1, largo):
                if lista[index] == min:
                    yield min   

            # Hay que elegir un nuevo minimo para el siguiente ciclo.
            # El nuevo minimo tiene que ser mayor que el actual minimo.
            # (Cualquier valor mayor sirve).
            found = False
            for index in range(largo):
                if lista[index] > min:
                    idx = index
                    found = True
                    break;

            # Actualizar para el siguiente ciclo.
            min_prev = min
            min = lista[idx]
        

tests  = [
    [],
    [0],
    [0, 1],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 0],
    [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    [3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
    [3,2,1,0,-1,-2],
    ["zanahoria", "beterraga", "apio", "lechuga", "tomate"]
    ]


#print([value for value in my_sort([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])])
for test in tests:
    print("Lista original:", test)
    print("Lista ordenada:", [value for value in my_sort(test)])
```

lo que produce:

```
Lista original: []
Lista ordenada: []
Lista original: [0]
Lista ordenada: [0]
Lista original: [0, 1]
Lista ordenada: [0, 1]
Lista original: [0, 1, 2]
Lista ordenada: [0, 1, 2]
Lista original: [2, 1, 0]
Lista ordenada: [0, 1, 2]
Lista original: [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
Lista ordenada: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Lista original: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
Lista ordenada: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
Lista original: [3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
Lista ordenada: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
Lista original: [3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2]
Lista ordenada: [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
Lista original: ['zanahoria', 'beterraga', 'apio', 'lechuga', 'tomate']
Lista ordenada: ['apio', 'beterraga', 'lechuga', 'tomate', 'zanahoria']
```